# How to make my Tcl/Tk wish application print debug stuff to console?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have this program:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/wish
package require Tk

# Window properties
wm title . "Jau"
wm minsize . 320 240

# main frame
grid [ttk::frame .f -padding "0 0 0 0"] -column 0 -row 0 -sticky nwes
grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1; grid rowconfigure . 0 -weight 1

# drawing canvas
canvas .f.canvas -bg darkgreen
place .f.canvas -relwidth 1.0 -relheight 1.0

# cmd
ttk::entry .f.cmd -textvar cmd -width 30
pack .f.cmd -anchor s -side top

puts stderr "hello world"
```

When I run it there is no "hello world" being printed in the console. Is there any way of getting `puts stderr` to work?

Using Win10 and PowerShell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr:** The simplest way is to run the application with `tclsh` instead of `wish`. Otherwise, use `console show` (in your script).

---

On Windows, `wish` is built to be an application that doesn't have a real console. That's usually useful as it prevents a window from popping up when people use applications written in Tcl/Tk, but in this case it means that it isn't writing to somewhere where your PowerShell console can see it. Instead, it provides a fake console-like thing that is displayed by default when used interactively, but which is hidden when a script is provided (under the assumption that the script is an application, the overwhelmingly common case). You can reveal that fake console with the `console show` command, but the output still won't actually be made available to PowerShell. (It'd need to use DDE or COM to interact with it, the use of which with Tcl are topics which are rather large in themselves.)

If you want to be able to talk directly to a Tcl interpreter over the standard I/O channels on Windows, you instead need to use `tclsh` as that configures those channels to actually exist. The remainder of what is required you already have: the `package require Tk` is sufficient to load the Tk package and transform `tclsh` into working virtually the same as `wish` (installing the GUI handling event loop for you, making the main toplevel `.` window, etc.) The key difference is that if you launched your script that way from somewhere like the Start menu or a desktop shortcut, you'd see an extra console window pop up even if no output was ever written with `puts`, but when you want the output that you write to show up in the outside world, that's what you need.

Comment: I chose to run 'tclsh.exe .\jau.tcl' from console during development. The console output is meant for developers and possibly powerusers running the application in pipe. 'console show' would be annoying for naive users, and un-pipable for powerusers.

Comment: @Andreas I suspected that was the right answer for you. I just wanted to make sure that the other alternatives were also mentioned; someone with a related problem might find them useful and the background also indicates _why_ this choice is necessary.